# Debugging JavaScript in Internet Explorer on Windows Phone

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone

It is possible to emulate Windows Phone in F12 Dev Tools, but occasionally something works on desktop but do not on phone. How can I debug JavaScript in Internet Explorer on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch Visual Studio and press Ctrl + Shift + P (or navigate to Debug > Other Debug Targets > Debug Windows Phone Internet Explorer).

More information in the section *Debugging Without a Visual Studio Project* in [Diagnosing Mobile Website Issues on Windows Phone 8.1 with Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/04/diagnosing-mobile-website-issues-on-windows-phone-8-1-with-visual-studio.aspx).